# About introducing a family of types into a type theory with inference rules

Tags: logic, type-theory, dependent-types

Suppose I want to introduce a new family of types $B(a)$, where $a:A$ into a type theory using inference rules. First of all, my understanding is that $B:A\to U$, where $U$ is some universe. So my first question is: should I necessarily introduce the universe $U$ before introducing the family $B(a)$?

And secondly, assuming that $U$ is already introduced, which rule would I use: this one --

$$\frac{a:A \quad B:A\to U}{B(a)\text { type}}$$

or this one --

$$\frac{}{a:A, B:A\to U \vdash B(a) \text{ type} }$$

or some other one? And what's the difference between these two rules? They both seem to be saying the same -- namely that if $a:A$ and $B:A\to U$, then $B(a)$ is a type.